# SharedPreferences: Why is my value not overwritten?

Tags: java, android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I am trying to overwrite a value in SharedPreferences. It's a Boolean but somehow it seems buggy or I am doing something wrong. Check out this little code snippet:

```
sharedPref.edit().remove("bool1");
sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("bool1", true);
sharedPref.edit().commit();
Log.v("TEST" ,"" + sharedPref.getBoolean("bool1", true));
```

Output will be:

```
2020-01-26 19:37:48.244 29886-29886/de.rich.richquotes.richquotes V/TEST: false
```

I couldn't find answer on this on the internet. Does anyone know?

Comment: Commit also after the remove....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call [`sharedPref.edit()`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android10-release:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java;bpv=0;bpt=1;l=357), it creates a new [`SharedPreferences.Editor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) object, which has its own map of key-value pairs which you can then [`commit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) or [`apply()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) to persist them. When you call `edit()` again, it will create a new object which will not have the edits you made to the one before. Instead you can do something like this (all this methods return itself so you can chain them)

```
sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("bool1", true).commit();
```

Also, if you don't care whether the commit was successful, you should use `apply()` instead. It's asynchronous but makes changes also in-memory immediately so you shouldn't notice any difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So is it better to use apply?

Comment: Yes, `apply()` writes to disk asynchronously so it won't block your thread like `commit()` while it's writing to disk.